# powershell- flagwords, text file with flagword values and checking the checkbox assigned to the flagwords

Tags: powershell, checkbox

(Confusing title I know) basically I have a text box that the user inputs the "flag#" (i.e. 141558817) and clicks a button to run the value against the values in a text file. It searches thru the text file and splits it up into an array and then writes out the value depending on the Input from the user. I want to take that value and check the appropriate check boxes without the user checking the boxes.

the Gold Function parses the input from the user and then checks the .dat (txt) file adds up the values that equal the user input and displays the written values like

```
00 : Approved
01 : Denied
```

and so on so on. so the  141558817 value would equal

```
141558817
27 : Admin Adjustment Date
22 : Signature Attached
21 : Fingerprint Attached
20 : Photo Attached
10 : I89 Attached
05 : Signature
00 : Approved
```

I want it to take the above and then check the apporpriate boxes for those values

here is the full code of what Im talking about. (Im a NOOB at writing code but I think I have done well up till this point) I cut out some checkboxes that were not relevant to the user input value so the checkboxes will be askew.

```
#141558817 <- (flagword value user inputs)

#gets the flagword values
Function Gold {
$i=0;
$flags=@{};
$value=@{};

get-content -Path "FlagWords.dat"|foreach-object {
$parts=$_.split(",");

$flags.$i="$($parts[1])";
$value.$i="$($parts[2])";
$i++;

}
$get=$R2APPFlagBox.text;
write-host $get;

$j=($i);

while($j -ge 0){
    if($get -ge [long]$value.$j){
        $fill="";

    if($j -lt 10){$fill="0";}

    if($j -lt $i){
        write-host "$($fill)$($j) : $($flags.$j)";

        }
      $get=($get - $value.$j);


    }
        $j--;

    }
}

function boxes(){
#----------------------------------------------
#cordinates for each check box
#old
#X = row 1=27   row 2=137   row 3=247   row 4=357    
#y = box 1=13   box 2=44    box 3=75    box 4=106    box 5=137   box 6=168   box 7=199   box     8=230
#new
#X = row 1=100   row 2=300   row 3=500   row 4=700    
#y = box 1=350   box 2=400    box 3=450    box 4=500    box 5=550   box 6=600   box 7=650   box 8=700
#----------------------------------------------
#Generates checkboxes
$0 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox;
$0.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True;
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size;
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104;
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24;
$0.Size = $System_Drawing_Size;
$0.TabIndex = 0;
$0.Text = "00, Approved";
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point;
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 100;
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 350;
$0.Location = $System_Drawing_Point;
$0.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
$0.Name = "checkBox0";
$MainApp.Controls.Add($0);


$1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox;
$1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True;
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size;
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104;
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24;
$1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size;
$1.TabIndex = 1;
$1.Text = "01, Denied";
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point;
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 100;
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 400;
$1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point;
$1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
$1.Name = "checkBox1";
$MainApp.Controls.Add($1);


$2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox;
$2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True;
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size;
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 105;
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 25;
$2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size;
$2.TabIndex = 2;
$2.Text = "02, Supervisor Hold";
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point;
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 100;
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 450;
$2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point;
$2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
$2.Name = "checkBox2";
$MainApp.Controls.Add($2);


$3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox;
$3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True;
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size;
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 105;
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 25;
$3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size;
$3.TabIndex = 0;
$3.Text = "03, G28 Attached";
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point;
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 100;
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 500;
$3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point;
$3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
$3.Name = "checkBox3";
$MainApp.Controls.Add($3);

$5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox;
$5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True;
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size;
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104;
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24;
$5.Size = $System_Drawing_Size;
$5.TabIndex = 2;
$5.Text = "05, Signature";
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point;
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 100;
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 600 ;
$5.Location = $System_Drawing_Point;
$5.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
$5.Name = "checkBox5";
$MainApp.Controls.Add($5);

######################################### NEXT ROW #########################################        #X = row 1=100   row 2=300   row 3=500   row 4=700    
#y = box 1=350   box 2=400    box 3=450    box 4=500    box 5=550   box 6=600   box 7=650   box 8=700
#----------------------------------------------

$10 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox;
$10.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True;
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size;
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104;
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 25;
$10.Size = $System_Drawing_Size;
$10.TabIndex = 1;
$10.Text = "10, I89 Attached";
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point;
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 300;
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 450;
$10.Location = $System_Drawing_Point;
$10.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0;
$10.Name = "checkBox10";
$MainApp.Controls.Add($10);

}


function Main{
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; 
$global:MainApp = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form;
$MainApp.Text = "TheRejectorRemover"

#inserted uscis logo here
$MainApp.BackgroundImage=$null;
$MainApp.BackColor="#F0F0F0";
#$MainAppImage=[system.drawing.image]::FromFile("$($runfolder)\Modules\images\uscis_logo.jpg");
#$MainApp.BackgroundImage = $MainAppImage;
$MainApp.BackgroundImageLayout = "Center";

$MainApp.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1280,950);
$MainApp.StartPosition = "CenterScreen";
$MainApp.MinimizeBox = $True;
$MainApp.MaximizeBox = $False;
$MainApp.WindowState = "Normal";
$MainApp.FormBorderStyle="FixedDialog";
$MainApp.Opacity=1;
#$MainApp.BackColor="#003466";

$global:R2APPFlagBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
$R2APPFlagBox.TabIndex=3;
$R2APPFlagBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300);
$R2APPFlagBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,35);
$R2APPFlagBox.Font=New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",16,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular);
$R2APPFlagBox.Enabled=$true;
$R2APPFlagBox.visible=$true;
$MainApp.Controls.Add($R2APPFlagBox);

###
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.TabIndex = 4
$button1.Name = "button1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$button1.location =New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($R2APPFlagBox.Right),300);
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 85
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 35
$button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$button1.Add_Click({Gold});
$button1.Text = "Run Script"
$MainApp.Controls.Add($button1);
###


boxes;
$mainApp.ShowDialog();
}



Main;
```

here is what the Flagwords.dat file would contain its just a simple text file

```
00,Approved,1
01,Denied,2
02,Supervisor Hold,4
03,G28 Attached,8
04,Fee Waived,16
05,Signature,32
06,Fee Receipt Elsewhere,64
07,Void,128
08,Attachments,256
09,Transfer Out,512
10,I89 Attached,1024
11,CIS Match,2048
12,Auto Adjudication (ADN),4096
13,I131 Attached,8192
14,Transfer In,16384
15,Rejected,32768
16,ICF Lock,65536
17,Dependents,131072
18,Pending (A),262144 
19,Pending (B),524288
20,Photo Attached,1048576
21,Fingerprint Attached,2097152
22,Signature Attached,4194304
23,Inspector Stamp,8388608
24,Inspector Signature,16777216
25,I864 Attached,33554432
26,UNKOWN,67108864
27,Admin Adjustment Date,134217728
28,CR Base Fee Waived,268435456
29,Fingerprint Schedule Required,536870912
30,Adjudication Hold,1073741824
31,flag word 32 bit,2147483648
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough... Update your Gold function as such:

```
Function Gold {
ForEach($Control in $MainApp.Controls){$_.Checked = $False}
$i=0;
$flags=@{};
$value=@{};

get-content -Path "FlagWords.dat"|foreach-object {
$parts=$_.split(",");

$flags.$i="$($parts[1])";
$value.$i="$($parts[2])";
$i++;

}
$get=$R2APPFlagBox.text;
Write-Host $get;

$j=($i);

while($j -ge 0){
    if($get -ge [long]$value.$j){
        $fill="";

    if($j -lt 10){$fill="0";}

    if($j -lt $i){
        write-host "$($fill)$($j) : $($flags.$j)";
        ($MainApp.Controls|Where{$_.Text -match "$($fill)$($j)"}).Checked = $true
        }
      $get=($get - $value.$j);


    }
        $j--;

    }
    $MainApp.Refresh()
}
```

I set each checkbox to be unchecked, then added a line right after your `Write-Host "$($fill)$($j) : $($flags.$j)";` that finds the checkbox on the form who's text matches the double digit number for that match, and updates the `Checked` value to $true, and near the end I told the $MainApp to refresh to show the updated values.

Comment: sorry for the delay on this, long weekend. seems like i get this error, 
    Property 'Checked' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At Flagword2.ps1:7 char:40
+ ForEach($Control in $MainApp.Controls){$_.Checked = $False}
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Comment: for the most part, it checks some of the boxes and ill have to figure out why it errors out with the others. its a start!! thank you for putting me in the correct direction.